# Selecting by ID in Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: .net, nhibernate, castle-activerecord, orm

How can I write a criteria to return all Orders that belong to a specific User?

```
public class User
{
  [PrimaryKey]
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
  [PrimaryKey]
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }

  [BelongsTo("UserId")]
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}


return ActiveRecordMediator<Order>.FindAll(
  // What criteria should I write here ?
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
Restrictions.Eq("User.Id", userId),
```